# Apple Mach-O Linker Error when updating Parse.Framework

Tags: ios, xcode, parse-platform, parsefacebookutils

I just tried updating my Parse.Framework to the latest framework. Previously, I had v. 1.2 or so from back in April.
I removed the original Parse Framework and followed the steps and dependencies to add Parse.

FYI - if I build on my iPhone, the error appears. If I build on the Simulator, the error goes away.

Here are my linked frameworks:

[image: Here are my linked frameworks]

Here are my Framework search paths (I cleared these out after the initial error, to no avail)
[image]

And here is the error:
[image]

It looks like it has to do with the ParseFacebookUtils.Framework, but I can't figure out how to fix it. XCode definitely needs a better way of debugging this error since it seems like this question is asked a million times and everybody needs a different solution.

***Update***
I just updated to the newest XCode and this resolved the problem.
If anybody has any insight, please share...

Comment: It looks like it's missing the `armv7s` architecture you require.

Comment: Have you considered using CocoaPods? Adding Parse through it is painless.

Comment: @trojanfoe, I removed armv7s and I get a new error. So how can I figure out the architecture that I'm missing?

Comment: Using CocoaPods, I just switched from Parse-iOS-SDK to Parse and ParseFacebookUtils and I'm getting the same exact linker error. Come on, Parse!?!

Answer (score 0):

try to remove Bolts.framework, it helped me.